# Build equation of a curve with set of coordinates

Tags: calculus, functions, algebraic-curves

I need to calculate the intersection of two curves. I do not have the equation of the curves, but I will have a finite set of coordinates.

Is there a way to build the equation for this curve based only on the coordinates that I have, or do I need to know more about the curve prior?

Comment: it depends on you you restrictions on precision of calculations

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can curve fit those points and then find the intersection of these curves. For example, you can find the polynomial that minimizes the sum of squared residuals:
$$
RSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(x_i))^2
$$
where $(i,y_i)$ is the point and $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}a_nx^n$